# Is there a function for finding the midpoint of n points on sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I have a trained [Nearest Neighbor model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html)

[radius_neighbors()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.radius_neighbors) returns all the indices within this radius of n points (e.g. 5).
However what I want to get is the mid-point (i.e. center) of these n (e.g. 5) points. Is there a method in `sklearn` that can do this? Or any low-complex approaches?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second return value of the function gives you the indices of the points in the sample that you want. Basically the `midpoint` is formed by taking the mean of each column. You can do this with the `mean` method of `np.array` objects. Assuming the original set of points is `samples`, and that indexes of the desired points is `inds`:

```
import numpy as np
samples = [[0., 0., 0.], [0., .5, 0.], [1., 1., .5]]
inds = [1,2]
print(np.array(samples)[inds].mean(axis=0))
```

in practice `inds` will be given by radius_neighbors on your trained model:

```
inds = yournnmodel.radius_neighbors(your_query_point).asarray()[1][0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. So to clarify, the midpoint is the point of the `mean` of my samples: `mid_point`. But that midpoint will probably be an non-existing point in the sense that its features were calculated by the `mean` of the samples. So to get a real existing midpoint I will have to pass it through the trained model to get real points in the neighborhood of it  by e.g.` real_inds = yournnmodel.radius_neighbors(mid_point).asarray()[1][0]` and pick one of them?

Comment: Well, midpoint is usually understood to be the center of mass. You can do like you say and find the nearest in-sample point to the midpoint and call that your center But there is no a-priori guarantee that this will have any "good property" (consider three points at random on the plane, choosing one as the "center" will not tell you a lot about the others unless you already know one is near the midpoint of the other two). Ultimately it depends on your data and the problem at hand.